# How do I get a list of functions defined in an emacs-lisp file

Tags: elisp

Is it possible to get a list of functions defined in an emacs-lisp file? I found this sort of related answer: [How do I get a list of Emacs lisp non-interactive functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605785/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-emacs-lisp-non-interactive-functions), but it involves a map over all of the atoms defined, not just what is in a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file in question has already been loaded, then you can modify the code in the question you link to filter out the symbols defined in *other* files:

```
(let ((funclist ()))
  (mapatoms
   (lambda (x)
     (when (and (fboundp x)                     ; does x name a function?
                (let ((f (symbol-file x)))
                  (and f (string= (file-name-base f) "my-file.el"))))
       (push x funclist))))
  funclist)
```

If the file has not been loaded, you would have to scan it with [`scan-sexps`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Motion-via-Parsing.html) and find `defun` forms.

You might, however, prefer to use [`etags`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags.html#Tags) or [`imenu`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Imenu.html) instead of scanning the file yourself.

Comment: that is close, I had to change
`(and f (string= (file-name-base f) "my-file.el"))))`
to
`(and f (string= (file-name-base f) "my-file"))))`

That does work, although it is pretty slow. I will look into imenu. It looks like a good start.

Comment: @JohnKitchin That should have been `file-name-nondirectory`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a faster way is to look for the file in `load-history`, which will then give you the list of variables and functions defined therein.

Comment: Also interesting.

`(cdr (assoc "/Users/jkitchin/Dropbox/kitchingroup/jmax/jmax-bibtex.el" load-history ))`

leads to something like this.

#+RESULTS:
| jmax-bibtex-journal-abbreviations | (defun . jmax-bibtex-generate-longtitles) | (defun . jmax-bibtex-generate-shorttitles) | (defun . jmax-stringify-journal-name) | (defun . jmax-set-journal-string) | jmax-nonascii-latex-replacements | (defun . jmax-replace-nonascii) | jmax-lower-case-words | (defun . jmax-title-case-article) | (defun . jmax-sentence-case-article) |`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your asking for a non interactive approach.

With `M-x occur ENT (defun.* ENT` you get a buffer with more or less all function-definitions found in `(current-buffer)`.

Comment: This has all the same problems as Mirzhan Irkegulov's answer (which was likewise based on a regexp search for `defun`).

Answer (score 0):

use Imenu `M-g i` it will list all functions and variables in buffer

Answer (score -1):

The quick&dirty way: extract all defuns via regex. It works instantly on a buffer with 5000 lines.

```
(-map 'cadr (s-match-strings-all "defun \\(.*?\\) " (buffer-string)))
```

This returns a list of function names that are defined via `defun` in the current open buffer. [`buffer-string`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Contents.html#index-buffer_002dstring-2886) returns content of a current buffer in a string, [`-map`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-map-fn-list) and [`s-match-string-all`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-match-strings-all-regex-string) are taken from [**`dash`**](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) and [**`s`**](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) third party libraries (their GitHub pages explain how to install them), [`cadr`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Elements.html) returns a 2<sup>nd</sup> element of a list.

`-map` is analogous to Emacs built-in [`mapcar`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html#Mapping-Functions), it applies a function to each element of a list and returns a new list, `s-match-string-all` returns all possible regex matches in a string, parentheses in a regex denote a [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) (read more how to form [Emacs regular expressions](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression) from EmacsWiki).

If you run it in `eval-expression` (<kbd>Alt+:</kbd>), it will just throw it into [echo area](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EchoArea), but that's not what you need. So below are variations that work with custom buffer or file. [`with-current-buffer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Current-Buffer.html#index-with_002dcurrent_002dbuffer-2146) allows to temporarily switch a buffer, while some code does actions inside it, [`f-read`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-read-text-path-optional-coding) is a file reading function form another third-party library [**`f`**](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el).

```
(defun list-defined-functions (buffer)
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (-map 'cadr (s-match-strings-all "defun \\(.*?\\) "
                                     (buffer-string)))))

(defun list-defined-functions-in-file (file)
  (-map 'cadr (s-match-strings-all "defun \\(.*?\\) "
                                   (f-read file))))
```

Read [Emacs Lisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/) and try to come up with whatever is useful for you.

Comment: Good luck obtaining the functions defined by macros with that approach (e.g. virtually *all* mode functions, for starters).

Comment: And in any case, using regular expressions to parse s-expressions is crazy.